# Display the content of IP register

Tags: assembly, x86, a86

I need print the content of IP register. (a86).

I have interrupt handler:

```
int11:
call ipp
iret
```

And procedure ipp:

```
ipp:
pop dx
print dx
ret
```

And function print:

```
print macro
push ax,dx
lea dx, #1
mov ah,9
int 021 
pop dx,ax
```

But it prints a lot of strange symbols :)

Please, tell me what's wrong.

P.S. My knowledges in assembler are very poor.

Comment: Is `push ax, dx` valid command?

Comment: Yes, function "print" works fine.

Comment: What does `push ax, dx` achieve? I've never seen such syntax before.

Comment: push ax, dx = mov ax,dx. It works. Yes, maybe it's terrible code:)

Comment: [A86](https://fruttenboel.verhoeven272.nl/asm/a86man.html#para5b) provides a bit of syntactic sugar for the push instruction in the form of a multiple-operand version. `push ax, dx` is equivalent to 
`push ax`
`push dx`

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert binary value to text.
It must be '$'-terminated string. And then load that string's address to dx.

Also you have to make sure, that ds holds correct value.

Look at: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/73/25.html

Comment: Can you tell me, how to convert binary value to text, please? I don't understand... Sorry for my stupid questions.

Comment: Look at http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65302-assembly-string-integer-algorithms-win32-nasm/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems.

Here

```
ipp:
pop dx
print dx
ret
```

you remove the return address from the stack with `pop dx`. Where do you think `ret` will return after you steal its return address? Why don't you put the address back to the stack?

Also, with that same `pop dx` you corrupt the `dx` register value of the program that gets interrupted by your ISR. Why don't you save and restore `dx` in the ISR?

Yet another one... I don't know your assembler, but this line

```
lea dx, #1
```

looks odd. When you invoke `print dx` this line of the macro, IMO, should transform into

```
lea dx, dx
```

and that is an invalid x86 instruction. Does your code compile at all??? If it does, what does your assembler do with `lea dx, dx`? Does it make it `mov dx, dx` or `nop` or does it remove/ignore it?

What's more, function 9 of int 21h displays a "$"-terminated ASCII string whose address is in `ds:dx` and you don't construct any such string in the code.

Your code never sets up `ds` and just uses whatever `ds` value happens to be in the interrupted program, which is bad. You need to save and restore `ds` if you want to use it. And if your ISR's data is going to be contained in the code segment of the ISR, you want to load `ds` with the value of `cs`.

And then `dx` has the offset of `iret` before `print dx`. Are you sure you want to print *that* value of `ip`? When do you want to know the value of `ip` and where?

Lastly, why do you have an ISR for all this?

Why don't you first make your `ipp` work without an ISR? And why don't you use a debugger?